# chromedriver crashing on Windows 7

Tags: watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Problem: When I run my tests, I get the following message in the command prompt

```
Started ChromeDriver
port=9515
version=21.0.1180.4
log=C:\Users\jhomer\Desktop\Workspace\WebAutomationTesting\Tests\chromedriver.log
```

Chrome then starts, after which I get a windows error message stating the chromedriver has stopped working.

Additional Information:
I just recently switched from a mac (osx) to windows 7.  I'm using the same IDE (Aptana 3) and I have installed the same gems:

```
addressable (2.2.8)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (3.0.0)
childprocess (0.3.2)
commonwatir (3.0.0)
ffi (1.0.11)
hoe (3.0.6)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.7.3, 1.5.4)
json_pure (1.7.3)
libwebsocket (0.1.3)
minitest (3.2.0, 3.1.0, 2.5.1
multi_json (1.3.6)
nokogiri (1.5.5 x86-mingw32)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rautomation (0.7.2)
rdoc (3.12, 3.9.4)
rubygems-update (1.8.24)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
s4t-utils (1.0.4)
selenium-webdriver (2.24.0)
user-choices (1.1.6.1)
watir (3.0.0)
watir-classic (3.0.0)
watir-webdriver (0.6.1)
win32-api (1.4.8 x86-mingw32)
win32-process (0.6.5)
windows-api (0.4.1)
windows-pr (1.2.1)
xml-simple (1.1.1)
```

I have run gem update, gem pristine --all, none of which have helped.

** update **

The error I was getting on the prompt after the tests "completed" is as follows:

So before I used the version you suggested I was getting this error:

```
Error:
test_UserRoles(UserRolesTest):
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/w ebdriver/remote/http/default.rb:76:in `response_for'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/w ebdriver/remote/http/default.rb:38:in 'request'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/w ebdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/w ebdriver/remote/bridge.rb:598:in 'raw_execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/w ebdriver/remote/bridge.rb:576:in `execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/w ebdriver/remote/bridge.rb:189:in 'quit'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/w ebdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:48:in 'quit'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/w ebdriver/common/driver.rb:166:in `quit'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdrive r/browser.rb:87:in 'close'
UserRolesTest.rb:48:in 'teardown'
```

Let me know if there is any additional information you may require.

Thanks.

Comment: More information on my system: Windows 7 32-bit, 3gb of ram, tests run successfully in osx, but fail in windows.

Comment: Probably good to note: Firewall both on and off, nothing changes.

Comment: Chrome Driver log file after test run: http://pastebin.com/VSkstuaX

Comment: It seems that the windows version of chromedriver crashes when the .close method is called on the browser.  That was the problem.  Is there another method for closing the browser upon finishing the tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the windows version of chromedriver crashes when the .close method is called on the browser. That was the problem. Is there another method for closing the browser upon finishing the tests?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and had to downgrade the chromedriver to version 20 (May 23). It works fine for me now on Windows 7 x64. Here's the download [link](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/detail?name=chromedriver_win_20.0.1133.0.zip&can=2&q=).

Comment: I tried using the executable you suggested and It's still crashing on my system.